# How to use class type passed as parameter to method to define local variables

Tags: java

I have a cache that compartmentalizes by namespace. I would like to use class type to determine which cache to use. The following method gives an idea of what I want to accomplish. I use the word `cache` loosely. I am more interested in correcting my design pattern so it works.

```
public static DObject getFromCache(String key,Class<T extends DObject> type) {
  MyCache cache = getWithName(type.getName());
  // ......
  type.class value = (type.class) cache.get(key);
  // ......
}
```

where DObject is a naming interface. How do I fix so that `type.class value = (type.class) cache.get(key)` works well? I know this would be a joke for Scala but I want to use Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T value = type.cast(cache.get(key));`

(You can declare variables of type T just fine, but type erasure means you can't cast to T. Luckily `Class#cast` is there to help.)

Comment: Thanks. What if I had just passed as parameter `Class type`, could I somehow use `type` for declaring? If so, how might that work? If necessary, assume that this implies no naming interface.

Comment: No, it can't be done. But the reason `Class` is generic is so you can get the actual type into a type parameter like this.